# Symfony 3.1 Cache - DeleteItem not working in prod

Tags: symfony, caching, redis, symfony-3.1

I've been using Symfony 3.1 with new Cache Component (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html), I'm using the redis adapter

config.yml

```
cache:
    app: cache.adapter.redis
    default_redis_provider: "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
```

Basically, I save data in redis when I do a GET to a specific resource, and I remove it from redis, when I do a POST..

With symfony in dev mode data is stored/removed from cache as I expected.
But when I change it to prod, the 'deleteItem' no longer removes the item from redis cache..
I cannot find any error in logs, so I'm getting a little bit lost with it..

This is a sample of how I'm using the cache

```
protected function getCache(){
   return $this->get('cache.app');
}

public function getAction(){        
    $cacheItem = $this->getCache()->getItem('example-key');
    $data = ... // Check cacheItem isHit() ...      
    $cacheItem->expiresAfter($this->defaultCacheTime);
    $cacheItem->set($data);
    $this->getCache()->save($cacheItem);        
}

public function postAction() {
    ...
    $this->getCache()->deleteItem('example-key');
}
```

**Update - I've found what might be causing this issue**

This is part of the code of symfony AbstractAdapter and RedisAdapter:

```
public function deleteItem($key)
{
    return $this->deleteItems(array($key));
}

public function deleteItems(array $keys)
{
    $ids = array();

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $ids[$key] = $this->getId($key);
        unset($this->deferred[$key]);
    }

    try {
        if ($this->doDelete($ids)) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    }

    $ok = true;

    // When bulk-delete failed, retry each item individually
    foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
        try {
            $e = null;
            if ($this->doDelete(array($id))) {
                continue;
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
        CacheItem::log($this->logger, 'Failed to delete key "{key}"', array('key' => $key, 'exception' => $e));
        $ok = false;
    }

    return $ok;
}

protected function doDelete(array $ids)
{
    if ($ids) {
        $this->redis->del($ids);
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is part of code from Predis StreamConnection.php:

```
public function writeRequest(CommandInterface $command)
{
    $commandID = $command->getId();
    $arguments = $command->getArguments();

    $cmdlen = strlen($commandID);
    $reqlen = count($arguments) + 1;

    $buffer = "*{$reqlen}\r\n\${$cmdlen}\r\n{$commandID}\r\n";

    for ($i = 0, $reqlen--; $i < $reqlen; $i++) {
        $argument = $arguments[$i];
        $arglen = strlen($argument);
        $buffer .= "\${$arglen}\r\n{$argument}\r\n";
    }

    $this->write($buffer);
}
```

When I call deleteItem('example-key'), it then calls the deleteItems(..) to remove that key..

The thing is, deleteItems() is calling doDelete() and passing an array like
`'example-key' => 'prefix_example-key'`

The doDelete(), then calls the Redis client, passing that same array `string => string`, when I think it should be, `index => string`,eg: `[0] => 'prefix_example-key'` instead of `['example-key'] => 'prefix_example-key'`

Then the redis client when processing the command to execute, receives that array as $arguments, and in the for loop, it does this:
`$argument = $arguments[$i];` since the array is in `string => string` format, it won't work, in dev mode, it shows **Notice undefined offset 0** error

This is the strange part

- In 'dev' mode, it will throw an error, and so, the deleteItems() will catch it, and try to delete the item again, this time, sending the arguments properly
- In 'prod' mode, the **Notice undefined offset 0** don't know why, but it does not throw an exception, so deleteItems(..) won't catch it, returns right there..

I've found a way to make it work for me, if I add array_values in the doDelete method, it works:

```
protected function doDelete(array $ids)
{
    if ($ids) {
        $this->redis->del(array_values($ids));
    }

    return true;
}
```

I don't know if all of this is making sense or not, I think I'll open an issue in symfony bug tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, this was caused by an outdated version of Predis, I tought I had the latest version of Predis, but I didn't

Everything is working fine with the latest version